# Running parallel based on variables from file in bash

Tags: bash, csv, while-loop, gnu-parallel

I've been trying to run a while-loop in parallel for a work that takes days.

I've seen other answers where parallel was implemented within a while-loop, but for that case it does work in blocks, where the next job only works after all previous jobs finished.

This is the code, which reproduced the two columns of the CSV file:

```
while IFS="," read fq tab
do
echo $fq
echo $tab
done < /home/samples.csv
```

where the csv file contain two columns with no header (column 1 and 2), where the variables are stored. For example:

```
a1,b1
a2,b2
a3,b3
a4,b4
```

I've been trying to run this in parallel so when a job is finished the other starts immediately because of the long run times.

This is the code:

```
while IFS="," read fq tab
do
parallel -j 1 --verbose --delay 2  "echo $fq; echo $tab" 
done < /home/samples.csv
```

But this produces

```
a1 b1 a1,b1

a1 b1 a2,b2

a1 b1 a3,b3

a1 b1 a4,b4
```

And not

```
a1   b1
a2   b2
a3   b3
a4   b4
```

Comment: if you need the results of processing `a1 b1` for processing `a2 b2` then you can't parallelize the code

Comment: To get your expected result: with parallel: `parallel -j 3 -a /home/sample.csv --colsep ',' echo {1} {2}`. Knowing if this will suit your final goal is an other story.

Comment: I don't need the results of a1 and b1 to proceed! They are independent in this case

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your ouput (wrong or expected); 'course, it doesn't help that you're trying to parse input lines with `IFS=","` but there are no commas in the input file; consider reviewing [How to create a minimal, reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then come back and update your question accordingly, making sure your expected output matches the sample input you provide

Comment: @markp-fuso, sorry, I thought explaing that it's a CSV with two collumns and no header would suffice. I updated the question accordingly!

Comment: The answer from Zeitounator should be all you need.

Comment: @GabrielG. plenty of people post they are working with a `csv` and then provide a datafile that's delimited by spaces, tabs, semi-colons, etc; net result: the *name* of a file doesn't tell us what's actually in the file hence the (normal) requirement is to provide the exact contents of the file thus removing any chance for misunderstandings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cat <<_EOF > samples.csv
a2,b2
a3,b3
a4,b4
_EOF

cat samples.csv | parallel --colsep , echo column 1 = {1} column 2 = {2}
```

If `samples.csv` is TAB separated, ; separated, or separated with spaces:

```
cat samples.csv | parallel --colsep '\t' echo column 1 = {1} column 2 = {2}
cat samples.csv | parallel --colsep ';' echo column 1 = {1} column 2 = {2}
cat samples.csv | parallel --colsep ' +' echo column 1 = {1} column 2 = {2}
```